# Ubuntu Forum registration problem

Tags: 14.04

I have now spent upward of 2 hours attempting to register with the UBUNTU Forum, however I am continually baulked by the message "incorrect capcha information". Every time I refresh the page, yet another incomprehensible string appears which could just as well be some form of pre-historic hyroglyphics. Any anwers to this problem would be appreciated from other users with more experience.

Comment: Are you trying to register at ubuntuforums.org?

Answer (score 2):

Contact the Ubuntu Forums Council

https: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ForumCouncil

> Contact The few ways to contact the Forums Council:
>
> Post to the Resolution Center if you have a problem on the forums.
>   E-Mail: ubuntu-forums-council@lists.ubuntu.com